# How to save jooq table as a variable and then reference it

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

This is my sql statement:

```
select count(*) from source s
join(select id as I from source where name is not null) e
on s.name = e.I
```

Here is what I have in java

```
    Source s = SOURCE.as("s");
    TableLike<?> e = create.select(SOURCE.ID.as("I"))
            .from(SOURCE)
            .where(SOURCE.NAME.isNotNull()
            .asTable().as("e");

    create.selectCount()
    .from(s)
    .join(e)
    .on(s.NAME.equal(e.I))
    .fetchOne().value1();
```

I think that TableLike is not the right type because I get an error when I try to do e.I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is (currently, as of jOOQ 3.2) no way to typesafely dereference the `I` column from your derived table `e`, as there is no way the Java compiler can know that there is an `I` column. You will have to resort to unsafe methods:

```
// Enforcing typesafety using coercion:
.join(e)
.on(s.NAME.equal(e.field("I").coerce(String.class))

// Circumventing typesafety using raw types
.join(e)
.on(s.NAME.equal((Field) e.field("I")))
```

A bit more typesafety can be achieved by reusing the `I` field as such:

```
Source s = SOURCE.as("s");
Field<String> I = SOURCE.ID.as("I");
TableLike<?> e = create.select()
        .from(SOURCE)
        .where(SOURCE.NAME.isNotNull())
        .asTable().as("e");

create.selectCount()
      .from(s)
      .join(e)
      .on(s.NAME.equal(e.field(I)))
      .fetchOne().value1();
```

Comment: I am still having trouble on with .on(s.NAME.equal(e.field(I))).  It wants me to either cast e.field(I) to (Select<? extends Record1<Integer>>)

Comment: Also should i still be naming what I select on? So you have TableLike<?> e = create.select() where I used to have  TableLike<?> e = create.select(SOURCE.ID.as("I"))

Comment: I am using jooq 3.9.1. Is there any type safe way to refer the columns in the derived tables in this version?

Comment: @yaswanth: Nothing better than what's explained in this answer is available.